# Brand new XPS 9560 & Ubuntu Mate 17.10 ... NOT WORKING

Tags: nvidia, fan, pcie

Able to log in but system freezes a few seconds thereafter. For example, I was able to open terminal and type three or so letters before system freeze.

While installing Ubuntu Mate 17.10, I selected download 3rd party updates.  Before this, while using Windows, I used Dell website to update bios and firmware.

I also notice the fans are practically always on even though I'm not even able to use the computer!  The fans seemed unusually loud (but not really loud) for some time once when I was using Windows (nothing but checking email!!), but eventually they did turn off and stayed off.  I am not trying to dual boot with Windows.  Secure boot is off, and I'm using AHCI and UEFI modes.

I did the full run of diagnostics, and no issues were found.

My understanding is that the problem(s) relate to one or both of these specs, but I haven't found a spoon-fed solution / troubleshooting routine, which I'm afraid I need at this point :(

- 512 GB PCIe SSD
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050, GDDR5 4 GB

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who can or tries to help!

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers for optimal performance of the GTX1050. Open Additional drivers and you'll find what you need.

Comment: Thank you for replying!  Because the computer freezes every time, I booted with USB and was able to pull up Additional drivers.  However, when I select the Nvidia one, it won't let me apply the changes.  It automatically reverts to the open source driver in use.

Comment: You need to do that in the installed system, not install it in live session where it's useless and can't be done anyway.

Comment: Gotcha.  The installed system freezes seconds after logging in.

Comment: OK, it happens unfortunately. The default open source driver is not enough for your chipset. Try this to add `nomodeset` so you can boot with reduced graphics that shouldn't freeze, then you can install the drivers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38834#38834

Comment: Actually, I tried a few more times to install the driver before seeing your last comment.  One time it started to install and stalled/froze halfway.  Tried again and it picked up where it left off, appeared to finish, but froze again.  Next time it said I was using the Nvidia driver, but the computer is still freezing very soon after logging in, and the fans get really unhappy once frozen.  Strange!!!!  Any ideas?  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: By the way, I don't even need good graphics, plus I would prefer longer battery life.  So I would like to figure out how to use just the Intel graphics ... but at this rate presumably that's not going to fix my problem.

Comment: You can disable the discrete graphics (Nvidia) at UEFI settings.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you recommend a link for help by any chance?

Comment: UEFI is what replaces the old BIOS, in case it confused you. And, as with BIOS, it varies a lot from one manufacturer/model to another. Please check your user's manual and/other documentation / online resources.

Comment: I read it's not possible to disable the discrete graphics at UEFI settings.  I tried this https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/63cavx/fixed_nvidia_1050_freezing_in_ubuntu_linux/ .   Improved the horrendous graphics but still freezing very soon after startup.  Now I'm at least able to navigate to click shutdown, but it hangs.  And now (after too many hits to the power buttom?), Ubuntu won't even boot.  Anyone want this laptop before I put it in the garbage?

Comment: Computer is working now.  Was using 17.10 before (would always freeze).  Now using 16.04.  Runs smooth even without Nvidia driver. 
 Only remaining problem is fans are nearly always on.